# Why is my await not working in my funciton? "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have a function -

```
async function run() {
  const drives = await getDrives()
  drives.forEach(function (item) {
    item.size = fileSize(item.size)
    if (item.mountpoints.length > 0) {
      item.path = item.mountpoints[0].path
    } else {
      item.path = 'N/A'
    }

  })

  app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('record', {
      drives: drives
    })
  });

  app.post('/record', (req, res) => {
    const pExists = pathExists.sync(req.body.path)
    const i = req.body.url
    const test = i.lastIndexOf('/')
    const id = i.substring(test + 1)

    if (i.includes("/album/")) {
      sid = `spotify:album:${id}`
    } else if (i.includes("/playlist/")) {
      sid = `spotify:playlist:${id}`
    } else {
      console.log('failed')
    }

    if (pExists === true) {
      try {
        await myModule.mount(req.body.path, userDetails.path)
        fs.writeFileSync(`${userDetails.path}/diskplayer.contents`, sid)
        res.render('success', {
          path: req.body.path,
          url: req.body.url
        })
      } catch (err) {
        res.render('failed', {
          error: err
        })
      }
    }
  });
```

And on line 60 I am trying to await for myModule.mount

```
await myModule.mount(req.body.path, userDetails.path)
```

But I am getting the error -

```
await myModule.mount(req.body.path, userDetails.path)
^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

Though my await on line 27

```
const drives = await getDrives()
```

Seems to work fine. I can't seem to work out what I am doing wrong..

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear: you cannot use `await` in a non-`async` function. Your callback function is not `async`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always whenever you work with Async/Await remember that we can use **await** only if the promise generating function or task is declared as **async** function. For using await, make the function in which it is used as **async** and making the global or parent function **async** has no effect. So in your case

```
app.post('/record', async(req, res) => {
....
await myModule.mount(req.body.path, userDetails.path)
....
}
```

will work.

```
const drives = await getDrives()
```

This line is in the run() function and not inside a function in run() function, therefore it works correctly.

Comment: Thanks, knew I was probably doing something stupid.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put async here (on your callback)

```
app.post('/record', async (req, res) => {
```

Comment: Thanks, knew I was probably doing something stupid.